# Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_stmt could not be converted to string

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm new to PHP OOP so this question must be quite dumb. 
I'm unable to create an SQL query through PHP. I've read the code many times but I'm unable to find any discrepancy and even the editor isn't displaying any error. I'm using PHP 5.5.13, MYSQL 5.5.24 and APCHE Server 2.2.22.

Following is the code:

**Test_signup.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>
            Test Sign Up
            </title>
        </head>
        <body>
                <form action = "Signup.php" method = "POST" name = "test_signup">
                Full Name: <input type = "text" name = 'full_name'>
                User Name: <input type = 'text' name = 'user_name'>
                Email: <input type = 'text' name = 'email_add'>
                <input type = "submit" name = "submit">
            </form>

        </body>
    </html>
```

Now coming to the **Signup.php**

```
<?php
$con = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'my_database');
      if ($con->connect_error)
      {
        echo 'Failed to connect' . $con->connect_error;
      }
      else
      {
        echo 'Connected';
        $stmt_chk_email = $con->prepare('SELECT * FROM `user_information` WHERE `Email` = ?');
        $stmt_chk_email->bind_param('s', $_POST['email_add']);
        echo $stmt_chk_email;
?>
```

When trying to run this code, I'm receiving an error:

> Object of class mysqli_stmt could not be converted to string

Of course the original query is much larger than posted here. I've edited the later part of the query as I figured out that the problem resides within the SQL "SELECT" statement but I'm unable to figure it out. Kindly help me on this.
Thank you.

Comment: Looks like you're missing a closing brace `}` after `echo $stmt_chk_email;` for one thing.

Comment: Are you sure you can `echo` something like that?

Comment: You're also missing `execute()` - You probably meant to use `$stmt_chk_email->execute();` instead of `echo $stmt_chk_email;`

Comment: @Fred -ii- Actually I haven't forgotten it in the editor. I just forgot to paste it right here. Any ways, thanks for responding.

Answer (score 4):

you cant echo this

<strike>echo $stmt_chk_email;</strike>

you maybe want to echo this

```
     $stmt_chk_email = $con->prepare('SELECT column1 ,column2,... FROM `user_information` WHERE `Email` = ?');
     $stmt_chk_email->execute();
     $stmt_chk_email->store_result();
     $stmt_chk_email->bind_result($column1 ,$column2,.....);
     $stmt_chk_email->fetch();
  echo $column1;
  echo $column2 ;
  .....
```

Comment: So how does the code know that the "?" value will be derived through the POST method?
I mean to ask that the above code does not tell that the email will be derived from the user's form.

Answer (score 0):

```
        $stmt_chk_email = $con->prepare('SELECT `column` FROM `user_information` WHERE `Email` = ?');
        $stmt_chk_email->bind_param('s', $_POST['email_add']);
        $stmt_chk_email->execute();
        $stmt_chk_emeil->store_result();
        $stmt_chk_email->bind_result($check_email);
        $stmt_chk_email->fetch();
        echo $check_email;
```

OR

```
    $stmt_chk_email = $con->prepare('SELECT * FROM `user_information` WHERE `Email` = ?');
    $stmt_chk_email->bind_param('s', $_POST['email_add']);
    $stmt_chk_email->execute();

    $result = $stmt_chk_email->get_result();

    if($result->num_rows == 1)
    {
         $result = $result->fetch_array();
         echo $result['column_name'];
    }
```