# mysqli_stmt could not be converted to string

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am having a problem when inserting data into MySQL. This is the error, and i can't find the solution.
Wheres the phpmyadmin camps and certains names in :

PHPMYADMIN - NAME:

1. email -> email
2. password -> pass1
3. nome -> nome
4. data_de_nascimeto -> data
5. pais -> pais
6. contribuinte -> n_contribuinte
7. endereco -> morada
8. codpostal -> codpostal
9. localidade -> localidade

Register.php: (`<form action="registo.php" method="get">`)

```
<button type="submit" name="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>    
<?php
                if(isset($_GET['submit'])){
                $date = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['data']);
                $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('-', '/', $date)));
                $inst=mysqli_prepare($connect,"INSERT INTO cliente(email, password, nome, pais, contribuinte, endereco, codpostal, localidade, data_de_nascimento) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
                $pw_hash=password_hash($_GET['pass1'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
                $inst->bind_param("ssssissss", $_GET['email'], $pw_hash, $GET_['nome'], $_GET['pais'], $GET_['n_contribuinte'], $GET_['morada'], $GET_['codpostal'], $GET_['localidade'], $date);
                if($inst->execute()==TRUE){
                    echo '<p>Registo efetuado com sucesso</p>';
                }
                else print_r($inst);

                }
?>
```

**EDIT**: (`print_r($inst);`)

```
mysqli_stmt Object 
( 
    [affected_rows] => -1 
    [insert_id] => 0 
    [num_rows] => 0 
    [param_count] => 9 
    [field_count] => 0 
    [errno] => 1048 
    [error] => Column 'nome' cannot be null 
    [error_list] => Array( 
                            [0] => Array( 
                                            [errno] => 1048 
                                            [sqlstate] => 23000 
                                            [error] => Column 'nome' cannot be null 
                                        ) 
                         ) 
    [sqlstate] => 23000 
    [id] => 1 
)
```

But name is with string on input.

Comment: `echo $inst;`  is not valid

Comment: You can't write echo $inst;

Comment: use print_r($inst);

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli\_stmt could not be converted to string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21635879/catchable-fatal-error-object-of-class-mysqli-stmt-could-not-be-converted-to-str)

Comment: @RaviHirani I don't think so, it says "nome" is null but it isnt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see is you have a typo in the `bind_param` section of your code.

What you have:

```
$inst->bind_param("ssssissss", $_GET['email'], $pw_hash, $GET_['nome'], $_GET['pais'], $GET_['n_contribuinte'], $GET_['morada'], $GET_['codpostal'], $GET_['localidade'], $date);
```

You are calling `$GET_['nome']` instead of `$_GET['nome']`. Notice the **underscore** in the wrong place. Which is why the value isn't being pulled in.

Same with `$GET_['n_contribuinte']`, `$GET_['morada']`, `$GET_['codpostal']` and `$GET_['localidade']`.

Comment: Thank you for proving it's not duplciate; OFFTOPIC- After login it uses session to save email, in profile info should i dump the session or do a select? Which is more safe since some people use browser with no cookies.

Comment: Hi Firmeza, you shouldn't ask a second question in another question. You can post a new question asking about the sessions, but first search Stack Overflow for something similar to your problem. Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740845/php-session-without-cookies